# Error from WordPress get_results() call

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a jQuery .load() in a script:

```
$('#category2').load("/wp-content/themes/mydomain/categories.php",
                            { category_number : 2,   // category to get
                              category_1 : category_1,
                              category_2 : category_2,
                              category_3 : category_3,
                              category_4 : category_4,
                              category_5 : category_5,
                              category_6 : category_6,
                              category_7 : category_7
                            },
                            function(responseTxt, textStatus, xhr) {
                                console.log("responseTxt=" + responseTxt + ", textStatus=" + textStatus + ", xhr->status=" + xhr.statusText);
                            })
```

And in the categories.php handler for the .load()  I currently have:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);


global $wpdb;
$query=("SELECT Cat2
         FROM wp_categories
         WHERE Cat3 IS NULL AND Cat4 IS NULL AND Cat5 IS NULL AND Cat6 IS NULL");
$dropdown = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
print_r ($dropdown);
?>
```

But I'm getting an error from the $dropdown = line above: "Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object."

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your php file isn't in "wordpress environment", i.e., wp code isn't included in it. You should manually include `wp-load.php` at the beginning of your file or make use of wp ajax api (best choice, btw). Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748211/update-option-doesnt-work-in-single-php-file/35749658#35749658), it will make things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `/wp-content/themes/mydomain/categories.php` file directly, rather than passing it through WordPress. This means the `$wpdb` object is not available for use.

You can confirm this by loading the `categories.php` file directly, and putting:

```
global $wpdb;
print_r($wpdb);
```

You won't get the WordPress Database object (unless you include the required files within categories.php directly.

You should be using the built-in WordPress [Ajax functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for handling Ajax requests.

There are a lot of tutorials out there that explain how to use Ajax in WordPress:

- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/
- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-to-load-search-results/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/